# How to make hash in PHP and Node.js have the same value?

Tags: php, hash, node.js, md5, signature

In node.js, I have:

```
var h = crypto.createHash("md5");   // md5
h.update("AAA");
h.digest("hex");
```

In PHP I have:

```
md5("AAA");
```

However, both have different value.   How can I make it the same?  or else, what other algorithm I should use to make them the same, so that I can use it as signature calculation.   Thanks.

---

Oppss.. actually. my mistake.  when I test it, there is a bug..   it will md5 the same thing.

Comment: Those both output the exact same value for me: e1faffb3e614e6c2fba74296962386b7. What versions of node and php are you using?

Comment: You should create hash in one statement as below...

Comment: If your string contents non 1-byte length characters (**l'Entrecôte** for example) use Buffer instead string --> `crypto.createHash('md5').update(new Buffer(ts)).digest('hex')`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple googling I did in the past gave me => http://japhr.blogspot.com/2010/06/md5-in-nodejs-and-fabjs.html

### Node.js

**Script:**

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update('AAA').digest("hex");
console.log(hash);
```

**Output:**

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/node/hash$ node hash.js 
e1faffb3e614e6c2fba74296962386b7
```

### PHP

**Code**

```
<?php
echo md5("AAA");
```

**Output:**

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/node/hash$ php md5.php 
e1faffb3e614e6c2fba74296962386b7
```

The output for both PHP and node.js are equal.

### C extension

Also you might have look at https://github.com/brainfucker/hashlib which uses C implementation which is going to be faster.

Comment: Test your code with string that contains non 1-byte characters ant it will fail. For example **l'Entrecôte**

Answer (score 1):

Your code creates the same hash value for me, you might doing it wrong at some point

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with creating hash for non UTF8 string :

```
var non_utf8_str = "test_merchant;www.market.ua;DH783023;1415379863;1547.36;UAH;Процессор
Intel Core i5-4670 3.4GHz;Память Kingston DDR3-1600 4096MB
PC3-12800;1;1;1000;547.36";
```

The results in PHP and NodeJS was different until I used [utf8](https://www.npmjs.com/package/utf8) library.
So following code works equivalent for both PHP and NodeJS :

```
crypto.createHash('md5').update(utf8.encode(non_utf8_str)).digest('hex');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(password, 'latin1', 'latin1').digest('hex');
```

This worked for me. Try different encodings: 'utf8', 'ascii', or 'latin1'.